# Cant set Custom Pin Image In MapView, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, mkpinannotationview

**Mini-Map Code:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

@IBOutlet weak var ProfileMapView: MKMapView!

func mapView(_ ProfileMapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation.isMember(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "ProfilePinView"

    var pinView = ProfileMapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    }
    pinView!.canShowCallout = true
    pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "CustomPinImage")
    return pinView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let LightHouseLocation = CoordinatesTemplate
    // Drop a pin
    let lightHouse = MKPointAnnotation()
    lightHouse.coordinate = LightHouseLocation
    lightHouse.title = barNameTemplate
    lightHouse.subtitle = streetNameTemplate
    ProfileMapView.addAnnotation(lightHouse)
}
```

why doesn't it work? why i can't get my custom image to work as the pin image? it works on another view controller for me.
thanks ahead

Comment: did you set your viewController as map delegate?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: add in your viewDidLoad this line `self.ProfileMapView.delegate = self`

Comment: let me know if solves your issue @RandomGeek

Comment: it did ! thanks ! can u make it an answer so i can mark as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you´re missing add your `UIViewController` as delegate of your `MKMapView` so you need to add this line in your `viewDidLoad` as I said in my comments

```
self.ProfileMapView.delegate = self
```

I also recommend you to use the **extension** pattern to make your code more readable

```
extension YourViewController : MKMapViewDelegate{

    func mapView(_ ProfileMapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation.isMember(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "ProfilePinView"

        var pinView = ProfileMapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)}
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "CustomPinImage")

        return pinView

    }
}
```